# firebase : CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, authentication

i work on the auth for my flutter app with firebase and i have an erro with the creation of a user, with the function `createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: mail, password: password);` and `signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: mail, password: password);` but it's not work, when i test it, it's mark that :
[`[firebase_auth/internal-error]{"error":{"code":400,"message":"CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND","errors":[{"message":"CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND","domain":"global","reason":"invalid"}]}}`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLbpN.png)

[and on my firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ipGQ.png)

if you want my code, go here : [my code](https://ayvemgroup.000webhostapp.com/txt.txt)
if you can help me, i am open for all solution

Answer (score 25):

I've experienced the same error. For me, the issue was simply because Firebase Auth was not setup before use.

1. Go to Firebase Console > Authentication
2. Turn on one or more authentication methods
3. Try running app again

Comment: You're a life saver - for me I literally just had to go to the authentication page and click 'get started' and it worked from there. Thank you.

Comment:   I wouldn't have figured that out.  Thank you. 
(also, who knew you could do emoji's here!?! - I thought I'd try it and it worked!)

Comment: I was poking around in all the wrong places when this helpful solution popped up!

Answer (score 1):

Follow the tutorial here: https://blog.flutterflow.io/firebase-authentication/

Depending on your app, you'll need to add the correct provider in Firebase under "Build - Authentication". I used the FinWallet example, which requires the email/password provider.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the Firebase: Error(Configuration not found). Firebase Auth was not enabled yet.

- Go to Firebase Console -> Authentication -> Sign-in-method
- Turn on one or more authentication methods
- Then restart your app

I hope the issue will be resolved.

Answer (score -1):

You need to initialize your app with the app config before doing any calls to firebase's services :)

Comment: i try it but i don't know what is missing